# jQuery deferreds with condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, deferred

I have some ajax calls that evaluate parallel with jQuery deferreds.
Now I want to add another call. This call is unique because I have to call it several times depending on what happens after I call it the first or the second time. For example, if the first call results in false, I call it one more time with different parameters, and when it results in true, I call another 3 variants.
I need the first call of this new tree to be launched simultaneously with the others, 'old' calls, already part of the jQuery deferreds.
It is possible to do something like this?

Edit:
I tried to something like this but the deferred ends before being evaluated, all of the call.

```
deferreds.push(
    $.when(     
        ajax(path, {type: 1, kind: 2})              
    ).then(function( data ) {
        if (data !== true){                 
            $.when( 
                ajax(path, {type: 1, kind: 1})                          
            ).then(function( data2 ) {
                if (data2 == true){
                    for(var t = 2; t < 5; t++){
                        ajax(path, {type: t, kind: 1});         
                    }               
                }           
            });
        } else {
            for(var t = 2; t < 5; t++){
                ajax(path, {type: t, kind: 2});             
            }
        }
    })
);  

$.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function(){ 
...
```

Comment: Can you please add to this question the code you have tried?

Comment: Also, without seeing any code this is a stab in the dark, but here's some great documentation on `Promises` which you could use to manage your async calls: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises#t=201703230132067913432

Comment: @potench I added code